# Is it possible to have localhost:8080 along with www? Or does the www mean that it is public?

Tags: java, web, networking, localhost

I noticed that google saml apps require the ACS url to start with "https://www." -

I'm doing testing on my localhost, and we have it set up to https://localhost8080, not "www."

My understanding was that you cannot have 'www' with localhost, as www implies that it is on the world wide web, and my localhost is not.

Is this true? Or can I get 'www' for my localhost too?

Answer (score 0):

You can have almost whatever you like on the local machine. Just put the line

www.localhost 127.0.0.1

in your hosts file and it will load http://www.localhost

Windows its c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

MacOS its /private/etc/hosts

Ubuntu its at /etc/hosts

Flush DNS if it's not working but it usually works straight away.

The port 8080 should have a colon in front of it in your line - don't put ports in hosts though.

Comment: A colon, actually.

Comment: Hm, I did this, but it's still not working for me, when I try to go to 'https://www.localhost:8080', it's giving me a cert common name invalid issue...

Any idea?

Comment: @Jack_Frost you'll need to just use https not the port, as https defaults to 443 (no need to type :443) not 8080 - that's likely WAMP's http port. Provided you've a self signed SSL cert set up on your machine it will work on 443. If not, you can use OpenSSL to configure it - or just remove the s (http not https) and work on non-ssl (8080). (https://zuziko.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-https-ssl-on-wamp-server/)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why i was saying 8080 - I have my application working on https://localhost:8443

but even by editing the hosts file to say 
127.0.0.1 www.localhost

it's not working for me, and still loads https://localhost:8443

Comment: is the ssl.conf set up right? Might be listening on 443 and WAMP is using 8443. Check the .conf files and see. If it's WAMP or XAMPP its usually on the system tray menu